# Is it possible to bold a word by clicking on it?

Tags: ms-word

What I mean is, for example I have a text:

Hello, I am using stackoverflow

And when I click on the word "Hello", it becomes bold, but other text does not change:

**Hello**, I am using stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the following Word Application events:

- [WindowBeforeDoubleClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.windowbeforedoubleclick) is fired when the editing area of a document window is double-clicked, before the default double-click action. The current selection is passed as a parameter.

```
Public WithEvents appWord as Word.Application 
 
Private Sub appWord_WindowBeforeDoubleClick _ 
 (ByVal Sel As Selection, Cancel As Boolean) 
 Dim intResponse As Integer 
 intResponse = MsgBox("Selection = " & Sel & vbLf & vbLf _ 
 & "Continue with operation on this selection?", _ 
 vbYesNo) 
 If intResponse = vbNo Then Cancel = True 
End Sub
```

- [WindowBeforeRightClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.windowbeforerightclick) is fired when the editing area of a document window is right-clicked, before the default right-click action.

```
Public WithEvents appWord as Word.Application 
 
Private Sub appWord_WindowBeforeRightClick _ 
 (ByVal Sel As Selection, Cancel As Boolean) 
 Dim intResponse As Integer 
 
 intResponse = MsgBox("Selection = " & Sel & vbLf & vbLf _ 
 & "Continue with operation on this selection?", _ 
 vbYesNo) 
 If intResponse = vbNo Then Cancel = True 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible in Word to apply any character formatting, such as bold, to any word by clicking it, if you use the Format Painter as follows:

1. Select a word that already has the formatting that you are after (e.g.
   select a word that is bold).
2. Double-click the Format Painter button on the toolbar/ribbon.  This "copies" the *formatting* of the selected word into memory.
3. Click in the middle of the word which you want to format (e.g. make bold).  This "pastes" the formatting you copied in the previous step.  The word you click will become formatted with the same character formatting as the word you selected in Step 1 (e.g. the whole word will become bold with a single click).
4. OPTIONAL.  Scroll using the mouse and the scroll bars to find additional words and click them to format them as well. You can also select text with the mouse (click and drag) to make it bold.
5. To stop format painting, click the Format Painter button again, one time.  Using arrow keys to navigate, or Esc, or other keys to type text may also stop the Format Painter.  The Format Painter button on the Ribbon changes appearance to show when it is depressed (Format Painter active) or not (Format Painter inactive).

Note: if you single-click the Format Painter button at Step 2, it will let you "paint" the formatting one time only.

Note: if you selected an entire paragraph in Step 1 before clicking the Format Painter, you can subsequently apply *paragraph formatting* to the paragraph(s) you click as well as *character formatting* to the word(s) you click (or click and drag over one or more entire paragraphs to apply both paragraph and character formatting.

The Format Painter is a great tool for applying formatting throughout your document.  If you get the hang of the Format Painter, the next step is to learn how to apply, modify and create styles, which are named sets of character and paragraph formatting settings.  The pros rely on styles to ensure consistent formatting and to format Tables of Contents and other complex fields.